Authentication failed Agora.io on Chat-SDK
I am implementing Chat-SDK from Agora.io. I am generating user token using npm library agora-token in a Node.js service, I execute
const token = ChatTokenBuilder
      .buildUserToken(appChatId, appCertificate, agoraUserId, tokenDurationInSecond);

with the right appId, appCertificate, and agoraUserId that I get from agora console.
Why does my client app (iOS + Android + Web) still get "Authentication failed" when connect to agora?
Successfully connect to chat-agora

It sounds like you might be using the wrong identifier for authentication. For chat product, Agora requires the user's UUID registered from the RESTful API for authentication, not the user's ID got from agora console. Here’s how you can ensure you are using the correct UUID:
1. Register the User: If you haven't registered the user yet, you need to do so through the Agora RESTful API to obtain their UUID. Here’s an example of how to register a user:
curl -X POST \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer {APP_TOKEN}' \
  -i "https://{REST_API}/{ORG_NAME}/{APP_NAME}/users" \
  -d '{
    "username": "{USER_ID}",
    "password": "{PASSWORD}"
}'

2. Obtain the UUID for an Existing User: If the user has already registered, you can obtain their UUID using the following curl command:
curl -X GET \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer {APP_TOKEN}' \
  'http://{REST_API}/{ORG_NAME}/{APP_NAME}/users/{USER_ID}'

3. Use the UUID for Authentication: When generating the token for authentication, ensure you are using the UUID obtained from the above steps. Here’s how you can generate a token using ChatTokenBuilder:
const token = ChatTokenBuilder.buildUserToken(appChatId, appCertificate, agoraUserId, tokenDurationInSecond);


Further reading
An Unofficial Simple Auth Server for AgoraChat App Demo

web
iOS
android

Refer to the Agora Chat documentation for more details on how to correctly use the UUID in your authentication process.

Secure authentication with tokens
User system registration


Hi, thanks for answering. Actually l already did the steps you mentioned. I already used a UUID which I got when registered a user.

If you have already used the UUID, pls verify that:
1.⁠ ⁠ Use the correct login(login with username + agoraToken) method
2.⁠ ⁠ Check if the UUID got when registered  is same as the UUID got when generated chat token via the parse script.

Hi thanks, appreciate your reply. I found my mistake. Turns out my client-side apps used the wrong data. I was using "UUID + token" instead of  "username + token".
